# get list of months using dseq from dateutils

Tags: sed, date, uniq

how'd I get a listing of the months in the year (abbreviated) using `dseq` from [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/)?

**NOTE**
simply running:

```
dseq 'jan' 'dec' -i '%b' -f '%b'
```

returns a humongous [list of months](http://pastebin.com/zaitsyy6):

piping the output to `uniq` reveals an out of order list of months:

```
Dec
Jan
Feb
Mar
Apr
May
Jun
Jul
Aug
Sep
Oct
Nov
```

Any ideas on how to correct the order of the list of months using `sed` or just by passing a certain parameter to `dseq`?

Comment: I know this isn't an answer, but: `seq 20130101 100 20131201 | date +%b -f-` worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the output using the following:

```bash
dseq 'jan' 'dec' -i '%b' -f '%b' | uniq | sed -r '/(Nov|Dec)/d; /Oct/aNov\nDec'
```

Comment: @richard lemme see the output please.  Post a pastebin or something.

Comment: I just noticed that, my previous comment is wrong. The input I used to test was wrong, taken from link in question, it has output of dseq twice.

Comment: @richard, okay, so what *are* you *trying* to say?  What do you get when you run `dseq 'jan' 'dec' -i '%b' -f '%b'`?

Comment: I am saying to disregard the comment, that said that the answer is wrong. ( I deleted it now ).

Answer (score 2):

Setting the increment to 1 month (`1mo`) only steps through the actual month names, the command would then be:

```
dseq 'jan' 1mo 'dec' -i '%b' -f '%b'
```

returns:

```
Jan
Feb
Mar
Apr
May
Jun
Jul
Aug
Sep
Oct
Nov
Dec
```

Answer (score 1):

This sorts by date and uses `sort` to make it unique:

```
dseq 'jan' 'dec' -i '%b' -f '%b' | sort -Mu
```