# How to generate list of months using bash?

Tags: bash, date

How can I generate a year's full months names programmatically using bash?

Comment: Why not `echo January February ...` as the names of the months don't change very often...?

Comment: Linking in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102548/117549

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`locale` will tell you the names of the months in the current locale:

```
locale mon
```

Thus:

```
$ LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8 locale mon
January;February;March;April;May;June;July;August;September;October;November;December

$ LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8 locale mon
janvier;février;mars;avril;mai;juin;juillet;août;septembre;octobre;novembre;décembre
```

If you want the months on separate lines, pipe the output to `tr ';' '\n'`.

Answer (score 5):

While preferring the `locale` proposal, assuming the GNU implementation of `date`, this one would run `date` only once in lieu of 12 times:

```
printf "%02d/01/2000\n" {1..12} | LC_ALL=C date +%B -f-
January
February
March
April
.
.
.
```

Comment: you might even drop the LC_ALL hard-coding, to allow the month names to be in the local locale by default?

Comment: Absolutely, yes.

Comment: The surprising aspect here is that the date interpretation isn’t locale dependent, and always follows the US format.

Answer (score 5):

You probably didn't mean to restrict it to bash, but ... you could.

Using *only* bash, but bash 4.2 or newer (to support `printf %(fmt)T`), and assuming only the number of seconds in a day (though it should be leap-second safe):

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(printf '%(%s)T' -1)
thism=$(printf '%(%B)T' "$now")
nextm=$thism
s=$now
until [[ "$thism" != "$nextm" ]]
do
  s=$((s+86400))
  nextm=$(printf '%(%B)T' "$s")
done
printf '%(%B)T\n' "$s"

while [[ "$thism" != "$(printf '%(%B)T' "$s")" ]]
do
  while [[ "$(printf '%(%B)T' "$s")" == "$(printf '%(%B)T' $((s + 86400)))" ]]
  do
    s=$((s+86400))
  done
  s=$((s+86400))
  printf '%(%B)T\n' "$s"
done
```

The initial assignments set up the current time in seconds and the current month; a "this month" variable is initialized to the current month, and a "seconds" variable is initialized to the current time in seconds.

The first loop gets us out of the current month by incrementing the "seconds" variable by a day's worth of seconds. Once we're out of the current month, print the new month's name.

The second loop runs through the year until we find the current month again; the inner loop inside of that loop increments the "seconds" until the last day of the month. Once that inner loop is done, we increment a day and then print the new month's name.  The outer (second) loop then resumes to completion.

Answer (score 1):

Using bash's *sequence expression* and *for* loop to iterate the *GNU coreutils* `date` command through the 12 months:

```
months() 
{ 
    for i in {1..12}; 
        do date +%B -d "$i/01/1980" ; 
    done ; 
}
```

will generate the `months` shell function which will output the 12 months full alphabetical name chronologically line by line.

---

**Explanation:** We are asking the `date` command to output a month's full alphabetical name (+%B), only for dates we specify (-d); in our case iterating through the 12 months by their numerical representation generated by bash's sequence expression.

**Note:** What's after the $i in the date string is only required to let `date` know the iterable's function by setting its relative position, thus the day and year in this snippet (*i.e. 01/1980*) were arbitrarily chosen.

Comment: `date +%B -d "3/01/1980"` says `illegal time format`.

Comment: it doesn't for me. Try with 03 instead of just 3 maybe.

Comment: So this works on latest bash (tried on Arch linux and it works) but not on older bash (tried on macos with bash version 3.2)

Comment: I suppose we're at low risk of an intercalary event, but I'll just note that this does assume a 12-month year. (and hard-codes the months to the ones from 1980)

Answer (score 1):

With the FreeBSD implementation of `date` (the one also found on macos):

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
  do 
    date -v"$i"m +%B
  done
```